# How to Fix Broken Packages?

Tags: 12.10, update-manager

How do I fix broken packages when it is not working? When I try to fix broken packages, it tells me to "fix broken packages."

Comment: Please put the error you are seeing in your question, thanks!

Comment: Seems like a case of trying to define loop - "loop: see loop" :-)

Answer (score 6):

My standard commands when trying to fix packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get check
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

or if it does not work (somehow deb did not finish installing)

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using aptitude : `sudo aptitude install <package-name>`
If you don't have aptitude installed, run `sudo apt-get install aptitude`.

Good luck !!!