# Wacom tablet, stylus and eraser dont show up in xinput -list(thinkpad

Tags: dual-boot, thinkpad, tablet, wacom

I am using Ubuntu 14.04(64 bit) on Thinkpad x200. The tablet is  working on windows 7(I have a dual boot). It used to work in Ubuntu 12.04(32 bit). I am now using

Here is the out pout from `xinput -list` and I see nothing about wacom.

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ UVC Camera (17ef:480c)                    id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
xsetwacom --list devices
```

to list my Wacom tablet devices, it works for me. (Cfr. also [this blog post of mine](http://bartssolutions.blogspot.be/2015/02/how-to-configure-wacom-intuos-express.html) about how I set up my Wacom tablet in Ubuntu).

Comment: The command returns nothing in my laptop :(

Comment: What does `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-wacom` return if you type it in a terminal? If it says you can install, install the package, log out and log in again and then try again.

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-input-wacom : Depends: xorg-input-abi-20
                            Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.14.99.902)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: You'll probably have to fix this before looking further into your Wacom problem. Maybe have a look at how to fix the "held broken packages" issue, eg. [How to fix broken packages](http://askubuntu.com/questions/285605/how-to-fix-broken-packages)... (which is for 12.10 but the commands are still the same)

Comment: Bart - The error is same even after following the instructions on fixing broken packages.

Comment: I'd say your problem isn't so much related to the wacom issue itself, but more to a general state of your Ubuntu install. What might be interesting is try to run Ubuntu from a live USB (see [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) and [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)) and see if your wacom is recognized there? That way you would know if it's a hardware issue, an Ubuntu issue, or the state in which your specific Ubuntu install finds itself. If it works from the live USB, you might consider doing a fresh install?