# Wifi not found: Ubuntu 18.4 / HP

Tags: realtek-wireless

Please advise (not an expert, please keep it clear and simple):

I installed Ubuntu 18.4 on my HP 15 laptop. Everything else I managed to fix but Ubuntu does not find WIFI. I googled and tried several suggested solutions but the solutions I tried did not work did not work because there are "broken packages".

How do I

1. Fix broken packages?
2. Fix WiFi?

Comment: Do you have `ifconfig` installed on the machine? Try running `ifconfig` in a terminal and add the output to your question.

Comment: Here is an excellent question about checking what driver you have, as well as the steps needed to install a PCI compliant driver. https://askubuntu.com/questions/333424/how-can-i-check-the-information-of-currently-installed-wifi-drivers

Comment: I did that and got:  'ifconfig' not found. Can be installed:

sudo apt install net-tools

I did that. This is the end of the output                                                      libdvd-pkg: Checking orig.tar integrity...
/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/libdvdcss_1.4.2.orig.tar.bz2: OK
libdvd-pkg: `apt-get check` failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting...

Comment: Thank you for the drivers etc. Will do that tomorrow....

Comment: lspci | grep -i network   gave me this:    *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a1100000-a110ffff

Comment: Did you tried running [`sudo apt install --fix-broken`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285605/how-to-fix-broken-packages) on a terminal window (ctrl+alt+t)?

Comment: May we see: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @Pablo Bianchi Installed 18.10 and during installation the system found WIFI and Bluetooth but once done both disappeared. Then, I disabled Secure Boot. Did the --fix and lspci please see below. Still no WIFI or Bluetooth                                                                                                 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822] Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [103c:831b] Kernel modules: r8822be, wl –

Comment: @ chili555 AND suddenly THE WIFI WORKS!!!! :)  Disabling secure boot was the solution. Now I just have to find a way to fix the dual boot....

Comment: AFAIK secure boot have nothing to with WiFi/network. Please update the question with the output of `inxi -SMn && lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` (what @chili555 asked and a little more).

Comment: @PabloBianchi Please see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1806472 From the bug report: "Yep, disabling Secure Boot seems to allow the driver to load no problem."