dist upgrade process seems to have broken 22.04.1
my system is booting but into TTY without networking so i can't update. I've tried to use a usb Ethernet dongle but that device isn't recognized. many commands are broken.The NetworkManager isn't starting. if i can get connectivity i can likely update the system ... any tips for gaining networking connectivity ?

is this connected with your previous question and is the instance you are referring to now actually 24.04.1? Please [edit] accordingly. Was the old question resolved?

no ... that issue was resolved this was a dist upgrade i attempted today ... that's broken ... can't get networking up to update ... i used a usb of ubuntu to try to reinstall however that option wasn't presented

The current version of Ubuntu 22.04 is 22.04.5 so you are 4 point releases behind. This ask Ubuntu Q&A seems appropriate in the circumstances. It may also resolve your network issue

i can't upgrade as my packages are broken ... can't determine what course of action to correct

try this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/420990/307670

i've tried that path ... however all those commands fail ... i'd like to resinstall ubuntu however i'm not getting an option to reinstall just setup ubuntu 24.04.1 alongside of 24.04.1

what .iso file are you using? and how are you trying to re-install? If you wish to install 22.04.5 you need to download it first from here
